# Where are solr.xml, solrconfig.xml and schema.xml located?

Tags: solr, cloudera, solrcloud

I am trying to create a new collection which requires change in these schemas. I am unable to figure out where they are located exactly. Any help in the direction would be appreciated.

P.S : I don't have admin rights. I am accessing using solrctl

Answer (score 5):

Cloudera has whole new approach about Solr Configuration (Cloudera Search).

solr.xml, solrconfig.xml and schema.xml are under solr_configs/conf folder (what you have created while adding new collection USING solrctl - probably at /home/solr)

Quote from Cloudera Search Reference:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-search/v1-latest/Cloudera-Search-Installation-Guide/csig_deploy_search_solrcloud.html

Configuration files for a collection are managed as part of the instance directory. To generate a skeleton of the instance directory run:

```
$ solrctl instancedir --generate $HOME/solr_configs
```

**You can customize it by directly editing the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml files that have been created in $HOME/solr_configs/conf.**

These configuration files are compatible with the standard Solr tutorial example documents.

Once you are satisfied with the configuration, you can make it available for Solr to use by issuing the following command, which uploads the content of the entire instance directory to ZooKeeper:

```
$ solrctl instancedir --create collection1 $HOME/solr_configs
```

You can use the solrctl tool to verify that your instance directory uploaded successfully and is available to ZooKeeper. You can use the solrctl to list the contents of an instance directory as follows:

```
$ solrctl instancedir --list
```

If you had used the earlier --create command to create a collection1, the --list command should return collection1.

ALSO if you have created a new collection and you want to update configuration you should use

```
- solrctl instancedir --update COLLECTION NAME /path/to/local solr_config folder
```

Maybe my answer is late but it'd help someone about similar questions.